# Proper authentication with a Django REST API through OAuth2

Tags: django, rest, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

For my application (in ionic, so Angular) I need authentication on my REST API powered by Django (1.7). And I want Google/Facebook/Twitter/Classic authentication through OAuth2.

The problem during my researches is that there are a lot of Django packages available, some have some problems with Djangon >1.6, some are incompatible with serializers and some seem poorly developed or received their last commit a year ago. And with some other, I'm lost in the documentation.

Do you have any suggestions of OAuth2 packages in a REST Django API (>=1,7) with serializers?

I've already tried (for the main ones):

- django oauth toolkit
- django oauth plus
- rauth

Do you have any good tutorials on those ones (still in Django API (>=1,7) with serializers)?

Comment: I would warn you against this approach - OAuth2 is an authorization framework, not an authentication framework so this can lead to security issues. For authentication, use OpenID Connect, which is built upon OAuth2, or SAML2. If you really want to use OAuth2, I've tried django-allauth with success against Github. It comes with full documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcanpilami ! OpenID seems to better fits my needs.

Comment: @Totem ,Marcanpilami how will we integrate openid connect with django-rest-framework.